# Warum heißt es die Unicef?

Tags: gender

Kann mir jemand bitte erklären, warum es *die* Unicef heißt? Auf Englisch heißt die Organisation "United Nations Children's Fund" (~ der Fonds), und auf Deutsch heißt sie "Das Kinderhilfswerk der Vereinten Nationen" (~ das Werk). Woher kommt das "die"?

Comment: Meine Idee wäre, dass es sich auf die Form bezieht. Also "*die* UNICEF" im Sinne von "*die* Organisation".

Comment: Es ist eine Ableitung von `die UN(O)`. Die einzigen weit bekannten „Organe“ der UN in Deutschland sind die UNO, die UNESCO und die UNICEF. Die ersten beiden sind grammatikalisch weiblich. Das wurde vielleicht einfach auch UNICEF übertragen.

Comment: Anderer Erklärversuch: UNESCO und UNICEF übernehmen klischeehaft „weibliche“ Aufgaben, im Gegensatz zu den „männlichen“ Blauhelmen. Möglicherweise hat sich deswegen der weibliche Genus eingeschlichen.

Comment: @Toscho: Logisch, deswegen heißt es ja auch "der Blauhelme". ;)

Comment: Vielleicht die Blaumütze?

Comment: Das ist eine sehr schwere Frage woher das kommt. Eigentlich sollten Firmen und Organisationen geschlechtsneutral sein. Dann heisst es aber auch "Die ARD" aber "Das ZDF". "Die NATO" aber "Der Bundestag". Ich kann aber keine Quelle finden die mir sagt, warum das so ist.

Comment: ARD - die Anstalt, ZDF - das Fernsehen, NATO - die Organisation, Bundestag - der Tag... da ist schon meist eine simple Erklärung dahinter... ich glaube dass das Wort "Fonds" damals einfach noch total unbekannt war in Deutschland und man sich daher wie von insertusernamehere an Organisation angelehnt hat

Comment: @Emanuel Das A in ARD steht für "Arbeitsgemeinschaft" - ändert aber nichts am Geschlecht.

Comment: where did you get that from?

Comment: Feminin Singular: Die US. Die UN. Die UNICEF. Die + Fremdwortabkürzung.

Answer (score 1):

Die Leute bringen die Unicef automatisch in Verbindung mit der UNO (weiblich). Somit lag auf der Hand, auch *die* zu verwenden, da anderweitig keine Assoziation (ähnliches Wort, markante Endung, ...) erkennbar ist. Ähnliche Wörter wären evtl. noch *die Uni(versität)*, *die Universalität*, die durch ihren weiblichen Artikel dies begünstigt haben könnten.

Comment: Oder der Unimog, der Universalschlüssel, das Unikat und das Uniformröckchen. Die In-Verbindung-bringen-Regel aus Satz 1, wo kommt die noch zur Anwendung?

Answer (score 0):

Ich schätze, es wäre richtiger, UNICEF als Eigenname ohne Artikel zu verwenden. So findet man das beispielsweise auch im [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicef)  (bis eben gab es noch eine einzige Stelle mit [weiblichem] Artikel, aber im selben kurzen Absatz fehlte auch eine Durchkoppelung - da hatte wohl jemand unsorgfältig geschrieben).